# first-child & last-child cross-browser compatibility

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-class

I realized I'm using these pseudo-classes pretty often, hence my question: In 2012, should I worry about older versions of IE and the way they would render the page? Of course I try to use them only when necessary, but they're really helpful and I would hate having to avoid them because of this.

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the thing. At the time I wrote the original answer:

- YouTube has [dropped support for IE6](http://mashable.com/2010/02/23/youtube-ie6/)
- Facebook's timeline [won't work in IE7](http://thenextweb.com/facebook/2011/12/30/not-a-fan-of-timeline-on-facebook-use-ie7-facebook-stopped-supporting-it/)
- Microsoft is [urging people to use at least IE8](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-10406468-264.html) (due to for XP users).

These are **big companies who have large user bases**, and even they are urging people to move or get nothing (or at least get basic functionality).

According to [this page by quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), `:first-child` is supported in IE7+, but `:last-child` is only supported in IE9+. Which means if you are planning to use this, you should get ready to forget the older IE altogether.

However, you can use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) which gives you leverage to make these styles work for older browsers.

Comment: I'll only try to use first-child for now, although according to the browser market share from feb. 2012 IE6 + IE7 only make up for 10%, so I guess I shouldn't really worry.

Comment: +1 great answer. made me realize something wrong iv been doing all alone.

Comment: Only problem with this philosophy is when you're trying to support a website where 45% of your user base still uses IE 7. Telling your users to upgrade their browser is even worse than supporting them.

Comment: This is all good and well unless you are working for a public entity, such as government. Then IE7+ support is required. At least for now...

Answer (score 4):

If they're used for eye candy, I would say go ahead and use them. However, if your layout relies on them for styling and so forth, I would put in some fallback methods for IE < 8.

Answer (score 1):

**:first-child** support till IE7 & above.

**:last-child** support till IE9 & above.

& if you want to check the compatibility of any selector check on this http://caniuse.com/#search=:first-child

Comment: Thank you, I guess for now I'll stick with first-child only.

Answer (score 0):

There are many variables to consider:

- which site are you talking about? Portfolio, governmental site, e-commerce?
- what's the percentage of IE6/7/8 users on this site (back when it displayed correctly on these browsers or on a comparable site that do)? China (IE6) or Korea ([a whole country locked with IE](http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser-KR-yearly-2008-2012)) are far different from Estonia or Finland
- what are you using these pseudo for? Eye-candy as stated by BenM or more important design things?
- what are the issues on IE6/7? How does it display? There are differences between quite ugly but readable site and text that get under images, disappear by lack of hasLayout ... completely unreadable.
- will your clients (if you are a web professional that have clients) pay the extra $/€ for IE7 compatibility and twice the bill for IE6? Do you even inform them of what you're (not) doing?
- if you're using a CMS, how hard is it to add `.first` and `.last` classes where needed? Can be easy in your templates and a PITA in poorly coded 3rd-party plugins. Or it can be hard because that's the job of your back-end developer colleagues and they won't listen to you...
- do you know about selector *tricks* like `p + p` (or better: `p ~ p`) for selecting every `p` except the first one. It can be a useful replacement to `:first-child` in some cases